# How to get data from dataset after server error message?

Tags: c#, sql-server

There is `DBCC PAGE` command able to read data by pages from database or log files like

```
DBCC TRACEON(3604)
DBCC PAGE('TESTDB',2,0,2) WITH TABLERESULTS
```

However it frequently contains server errors or warnings in reply. SSMS able to show it properly, there are "Results" and "Messages" tabs. I'm trying to get results with C#

```
var conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=PCNAME;Initial Catalog=TESTDB;User ID=user;Password=password");
SqlCommand cmdPageNo = new SqlCommand();
SqlDataReader readerPageNo, readerPage = null;

cmdPageNo.CommandText = "SELECT fileid, size FROM sysfiles where name = 'TESTDB_log'";
cmdPageNo.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmdPageNo.Connection = conn;

conn.Open();

readerPageNo = cmdPageNo.ExecuteReader();
if (readerPageNo.Read()) {
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(readerPageNo.GetValue(0));
    int pageCnt = Convert.ToInt32(readerPageNo.GetValue(1));
    readerPageNo.Close();

    SqlCommand cmdNQ = new SqlCommand("DBCC TRACEON(3604)", conn);
    cmdNQ.ExecuteNonQuery();

    SqlCommand cmdPage = new SqlCommand("DBCC PAGE('TESTDB', @fileid, @pageno, 2) WITH TABLERESULTS", conn);

    SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter();
    param1.ParameterName = "@fileid";
    param1.Value = id;
    cmdPage.Parameters.Add(param1);

    SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter();
    param2.ParameterName = "@pageno";
    cmdPage.Parameters.Add(param2);

    for (int i = 0; i < pageCnt; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            param2.Value = i;
            try
            {
                readerPage = cmdPage.ExecuteReader();
            }
            catch
            {
                // there are always errors and warnings
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (readerPage != null)
            {
                string temp = readerPage.GetString(0);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

but after errors `readerPage` is null in `finally` section. I checked data packet sent by SQL Server: after several messages (some with SeverityClass 16 that causes exception) there are fields definitions and values. Question is how to ignore errors caused by server error messages and get data from dataset like SSMS do?

Comment: check database to make sure each page is unique (not duplicates) in field "size FROM sysfiles".  If you have duplicates in sysfiles or index are not sequential you will have issues.

Comment: It is new database with 1 new table and 1 record added. There always errors on retrieving pages from log file (file id = 2) due to DBCC PAGE trying to explain ldf pages as mdf pages.

Comment: So should it be 'TESTDB_log.mdf' or similar.  So 'size' is returning a two instead of a one.

Comment: Log file name is 'TESTDB_log.ldf', in sysfiles `name` stored without extension, `filename` full path with extension. Size is amount of pages (including reserved and header).